# UINavigationBar weird color change animation when dismissing UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have a `FirstViewController` and a `SecondViewController`. They have different colors for their `UINavigationBar`. When I show `SecondViewController`, the color fades in fine. I recorded the animation with the simulator and slow animations.

[image: Animation Show]

However, when I go back from `SecondViewController` to `FirstViewController`, the color **does not animate** and everything just changes at once.

[image: Animation Dismiss]

This is how I set the code for the `UINavigationBar` in `SecondViewController`.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if let navBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {

        navBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
        navBar.barTintColor = NavBarColor.red
        navBar.backgroundColor = NavBarColor.red
        navBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
        navBar.isTranslucent = false
        navBar.tintColor = .white
    }
}
```

In my `FirstViewController` class, I created a struct `NavBarSettings` and save the information of the UINavigationBar. I then apply them in `viewWillAppear`.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if let navBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar,
        let navBarSettings = self.navBarSettings {

        navBar.barStyle = navBarSettings.barStyle
        navBar.barTintColor = navBarSettings.barTintColor
        navBar.backgroundColor = navBarSettings.backgroundColor
        navBar.titleTextAttributes = navBarSettings.titleTextAttributes
        navBar.isTranslucent = navBarSettings.isTranslucent
        navBar.tintColor = navBarSettings.tintColor

    }
}
```

I also tried to change the UINavigationBar information in `SecondViewController` `viewWillDisappear` but it had the same effect.

I've also tried to set a `backgroundColor` but it had did not change anything either.

How do I get the second animation to work like the first one?

**Update**

The segue to `SecondViewController` is of kind show.

I simply call it with `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SecondViewControllerSegue", sender: nil)`

I didn't add any custom code to the back button, it's the default `UINavigationController` implementation.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question, I have deleted the answer. Have you tried just setting the values manually instead of setting it from navBarSettings simply in your viewWillAppear method in your FirstViewController?

Comment: Yes I did, but no difference

Comment: Can you update your question with code with how you push the SecondViewController and how you pop it ?

Comment: @Sneak I updated the question. Does it help you?

Comment: I rarely work with segues and Storyboard navigationcontrollers I found it messy, I think your problem might be in some option in the StoryBoard but I am not sure, to make sure, you should try a simple instantiateViewController with your SecondViewController storyboardID and push SecondViewController by code and see if that makes any difference first I would strongly suggest.

Comment: It does not make any difference

Comment: I can't think of anything else. Except one final thing, did you try to put the code in both viewWillAppear on FirstViewController **and** viewWillDissapear of SecondViewController at the same time?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that before. Clinton found the solution, thanks for your help Sneak :)

Comment: Really wierd issue lol, Great is solved! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the back button with a custom back button and add an action to it.

```
let backButton = UIButton()
backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.backButtonClicked), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
navBar.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton 

func backButtonClicked() {
   // try implementing the same thing here but with the self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Thank you!:) the `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` part did the trick